# php inside javascript function not working in chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i was trying to put php code inside jquery code
here is the code snippet

```
html code

<div id="box">
hello
</div>
```

jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#box').click(function(e) {
     alert(<?php echo "hello";?>);

        });
      });
```

its working fine with mozilla but when i run it in chrome it shows error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

so what can be the solution for it

Comment: Just as a side note - something like this (server side) won't *only* be showing an error in one browser... Browsers are client side; they all receive the same information. Chances are that it didn't work in mozilla either.

Comment: @Nile its working fine with mozilla

Comment: The source of the files in both Chrome and Firefox should be exactly the same. Otherwise, something with the cache isn't right.

Comment: @Nile..i ve cleared all the cache.but still i am facing the same problem

Comment: Are the sources the same or different? Also, is this in a `.php` file/a file that's set to type `application/x-httpd-php`?

Comment: @Nile  source is same for both browser and its with .php extension...i ve not understood "file/a file that's set to type application/x-httpd-php"

Comment: This must be a server side issue. I suggest contacting your host.

Comment: Where are you expecting `<?php echo "hello";?>` to be executed? It cannot be executed client side, but must be done server-side. This means the server must be configured to understand the file contains _php_ (normally already done for `.php` files). The `alert(/*..*/)` is executed in the browser, client side. This means the two things are evaluated at different times by different machines.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the alert parameter function, like this:

instead of

```
alert(<?php echo "hello";?>);
```

quote it

```
alert("<?php echo "hello";?>");
```

because when you do not quote its like

```
alert(hello); //here hello will behave like variable
```

[live result](http://jsfiddle.net/J9xPb/)

but when you use quote its now [**string**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

```
alert("hello"); //here hello is string
```

[Live Result](http://jsfiddle.net/DnYqK/)

Comment: i tried it that way but its just give alert box with <?php echo "hello";?> string.its not executing the php code

Comment: Nikhil, it would appear that the file is not being parsed by the PHP parser, which is a server-side issue. Are you perchance making a "file://" protocol request?

Answer (score 0):

Your alert message itself isn't enclosed in quotes, it should be:

```
alert('<?php echo "hello";?>');
```

Also, make sure that the javascript code that contains PHP is inside your actual PHP file - PHP code in external Javascript files won't be evaluated at all, which might explain the weird error about "<"

Comment: i tried it that way but its just give alert box with
<?php echo "hello";?> string.its not executing the php code

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear as to whether you want to alert "Hello" or if you're trying to insert the string into the div, but either way you don't need PHP to accomplish this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#box').click(function(e) {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#box').click(function(e) {
    $(this).html("hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: that was just a dummy example.actully i want to set session variable in jquery function on the click of #box

Comment: Ok, you should update your original post then clarifying that, otherwise everyone will just think you need to alert something :) But in that case, you'll need a bit more code...

Comment: Do you have a php file you're working with?

Comment: its bit large so i ve just put the required code here.. and i have tried the same code separately(the code used in the query) but facing the same problem

Comment: Are you familiar with [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? This sounds like a good time to use it.

Comment: i know dat little bit..but i wanted to make it this way